# change the cell that contains your searchword

Tags: excel, cell

I'm currently facing this struggle, i will try to explain it like this.
The content of the cells: uml434, ffjdfuml434, uml32323.
I want to change these cells to uml only.
but in reallity there are alot more of these cells, and also ones that you dont want to change.
is there a easy way to do this?

Thanks alot

Comment: I am not sure you can give multiple cells the same name (unless it is a contiguous range)?

Comment: Are these cell names or contents of cell?

Comment: content of the cell

Comment: Loop through all of the cells (or put them in an array) and use the Instr function to identify those containing uml.

Comment: If you mean replace all cells which contain text `uml` then can you not do find (`*uml*`) and replace (`uml`) and replace all. Use texts without brackets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example that you can adapt to your needs.  In this demo:

1.the data is in column **A**.
2.the values are constants, not formulas

```
Sub umlChanger()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    s = "uml"

    For Each r In Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
        If InStr(r.Value, s) > 0 Then r.Value = s
    Next r
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks for the amazing help!

Comment: @Ericmansen  Thank you for the feedback.  Update the post if you require additional assistance.